# Change wordpress admin login url

Tags: wordpress

I am searching for already an hour but cant find anything. So I actually want when someone goes to  myblog.com/wp-admin   to see 404 error or some other error. The same thing I want a user experience when he goes to myblog.com/wp-login.php. So basically I need to restrict access to that 2 URL  and also how can I configure to have myblog.com/login to have the same login page that I would have in the myblog.com/wp-admin page? I am doing this for protecting my wp site from hackers.

Comment: Try [my three-step solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-admin-url-or-wp-admin-to-secure-login) on the WP support forum.

Comment: didnt work. threw not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your `.htaccess` file to accept only your IP address and you can also secure your wp-admin folder using a username/password.

The are lots of tutorials online about that.

Comment: my question is about bringing me an example. I know its an htaccess stuff

Comment: and waht i am working on a project with my friend ,everytime someone wants to work on a project the will have to enter their IP? I think there is a simple solution

Comment: Simple solution is to configure htaccess and htpasswd to password protect your wp-admin folder.